# How to solve a Pell's Equation?

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to figure out how to solve the following Pell Equation and I can't seem to remember how. Can someone assist me in the procedure?

$(2t+1)^2-8s^2=1$ where t and s are integers.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation. Fundamental solution is $3^2-8\cdot 1^2=1$.

Answer (score 1):

since the target is $1$ there are no alternatives to be considered; given a solution $(x,y)$ to $$ x^2 - 8 y^2 = 1,  $$ say with $x,y \geq 0,$ the next solution is
$$  (3x+8y,x+3y ) . $$
$$ (1,0)   $$
$$ (3,1)   $$
$$ (17,6)   $$
$$ (99,35)   $$
$$ (577,204)   $$

Notice also that there is a degree 2 recurrence for each,
$$  x_{n+2} = 6 x_{n+1} - x_n, $$ 
$$  y_{n+2} = 6 y_{n+1} - y_n. $$ 
Taking the evident
$$ A \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  3  &  8  \\
   1   &  3  
\end{array} 
  \right)  ,
  $$
this is just the Cayley-Hamilton theorem saying
$$  A^2 - 6 A + I = 0. $$
For that matter, although I wrote them as row vectors, all solutions are simply the left hand column of some $A^n.$ This observation is pretty much what you get from the quadratic number field terminology.